# How can I sort this data?

Tags: python, sorting, file-management

So, I'm working on a project in which I have to sort a large 34mb text file full of song data. Each line of the text file has a year,unique number,artist and song. What I can't figure out is how to sort the data efficiently into other text files. I want to sort by artist name and song name. Sadly this is all i have:

```
#Opening the file to read here
with open('tracks_per_year.txt', 'r',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
#Creating 'lists' to put information from array into
years=[]
uics=[]
artists=[]
songs=[]

#Filling up the 'lists'
for line in in_file:
    year,uic,artist,song=line.split("<SEP>")
    years.append(year)
    uics.append(uic)
    artists.append(artist)
    songs.append(song)
    print(year)
    print(uic)
    print(artist)
    print(song)

#Sorting:
with open('artistsort.txt', 'w',encoding='utf8') as artist:

for x in range(1,515576):

    if artists[x]==artists[x-1]:
        artist.write (years[x])
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(uics[x])
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(artists[x])
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(songs[x])
        artist.write("\n")


with open('Onehitwonders.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as ohw:

for x in range(1,515576):

    if artists[x]!= artists[x-1]:
        ohw.write (years[x])
        ohw.write(" ")
        ohw.write(uics[x])
        ohw.write(" ")
        ohw.write(artists[x])
        ohw.write(" ")
        ohw.write(songs[x])
        ohw.write("\n")
```

Keep in mind I am a novice, so please try to put your explanations in simple terms. If you guys have any other ideas I would love to hear them too. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `range` for this. If the number of entries in the file changes it will break your logic. You can use `for line in artists:` to make sure you always go over every line.

Comment: @IanAuld Thanks for the advice but, I did that in the beginning. The problem was that nothing got written in the artistsort.txt file that way and the one hit wonder file became far too large (~32mb).

Comment: That would have nothing to do with the `for` loop. In your previous question there was a problem with your logic that prevented anything being written to the file. The `for` loop just iterates over your data, it's what comes after it that decides what actually happens to your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could import your data into a dictionary-based structure, i.e. for each artist and song:

```
data = {artist_name: {song_name: {'year': year, 'uid': uid}, 
                      ... }, 
        ...}
```

Then when you output, use `sorted` to get them in alphabetical order:

```
for artist in sorted(data):
    for song in sorted(data[artist]):
        # use data[artist][song] to access details
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```py
from operator import attrgetter

class Song:
    def __init__(self, year, uic, artist, song):
        self.year = year
        self.uic = uic
        self.artist = artist
        self.song = song

songs = []

with open('tracks_per_year.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        year, uic, artist, song = line.split("<SEP>")
        songs.append(Song(year, uic, artist, song))
        print(year)
        print(uic)
        print(artist)
        print(song)

with open('artistsort.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as artist:
    for song in sorted(songs, key=attrgetter('artist', 'song')):
        artist.write (song.year)
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(song.uic)
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(song.artist)
        artist.write(" ")
        artist.write(song.song)
        artist.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. The only part of it I don't get is     "for song in sorted(songs, key=attrgetter('artist', 'song')):". Mind explaining.

Comment: Built-in python function `sorted()` returns a new sorted list from the `songs` list. The optional argument `key` is a function returned key from each element of the `songs`. In this case is the `attrgetter` function which returns `artists` and `song` fields from a `Song` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't beat the simplicity of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). To read your file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('tracks_per_year.txt', sep='<SEP>')
data
#    year    uic     artist      song
#0   1981    uic1    artist1     song1
#1   1934    uic2    artist2     song2
#2   2004    uic3    artist3     song3
```

Then to sort by a specific column and write to a new file just do:

```
data.sort(columns='year').to_csv('year_sort.txt')
```